# Does $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}te^{-|t|} \, dt$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Good evening

> Does $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}te^{-|t|} \, dt$ converge?

I have got a series of exercices without corrections so I carry on with a new exercice.

My solution :

$te^{-|t|}=\dfrac{t}{e^{|t|}}= \dfrac{t}{e^{\frac{|t|}{2}}}\times\dfrac{1}{e^{\frac{|t|}{2}}}$

So there exists $a>0$ such that $\forall |t|>a,\quad \dfrac{|t|}{e^{\frac{|t|}{2}}}<1\iff\dfrac{|t|}{e^{|t|}}<\dfrac{1}{e^{\frac{|t|}{2}}}$

Thus $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{|t|}{2}} \, dt=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \, dt$

Let $F(x):=\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{x}e^{-\frac{t}{2}} \, dt=-4\left[e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\right]_0^x=-4\left(e^{-\frac{x}{2}}-1\right)\underset{x\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}4$

As $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{|t|}{2}} \, dt$ converges, then $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}te^{-|t|} \, dt$ converges.

Is it correct and is there something more concise?

Comment: It works fine. A little more concise is that $t  = \mathcal{O}(e^{\epsilon |t|})$ using big-O notation

Comment: I don't see where you've shown there exists $a>0$. But that's the only problem I see.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art Because $\dfrac{|t|}{e^{\frac{|t|}{2}}}$ tend to 0 when $t$ goes to $+\infty$

Comment: Yes, but where was that shown?

Comment: @ reuns thanks for this comment,

Comment: Also from $f(z) = \frac{1-z^N}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n$ you know $f'(z) = \frac{1-z^N- N z^{N-1}(1-z)}{(1-z)^2}= \sum_{n=1}^N n z^{n-1}$ from which you can compute $\int_0^x t e^{-t}dt$ directly using Riemann sums.

Comment: Since the integrated function is odd, the value of the integral is zero.

Comment: @Anixx $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}t\;dt$ diverges

Comment: @reuns Besides that being somewhat begging the question, you have to show that $t<O(e^t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also integrate by parts to an upper bound $R$ and take limits as $R \to \infty$:
$$
\int_0^R t \, e^{-t} \, dt 
= \left[ t \, \left( -e^{-t} \right) \right]_0^R - \int_0^R \left( -e^{-t} \right) \, dt
= -R \, e^{-R} + \int_0^R e^{-t} \, dt \\
= -R \, e^{-R} + \left[ -e^{-t} \right]_0^R
= -R \, e^{-R} - e^{-R} + 1 \\
\to 0 - 0 + 1 = 1
$$
Since $t \, e^{-t} \geq 0$ for $t \geq 0$ this shows that $t \, e^{-t} \in L^+([0, \infty))$ and symmetry implies $t \, e^{-t} \in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but if you want something more concise:

---

Since the integrand is odd, it suffices to only consider $t>0$. Over that interval, we have

$$\int_0^\infty te^{-t}~\mathrm dt$$

Now apply the ratio test, noting that $te^{-t}$ is bounded for $t\to0$.

Comment: ,@SimplyBeautifulArt  I don't understand when you say $te^{-t}$ is bounded when $t$ goes to $0$

Comment: For $0<t<x$, we have$$0<te^{-t}<t<x$$hence it is bounded for any $t\in(0,x)$

Comment: I really don't know what I should do with this argument...May you tell me please?

Comment: @Stu Don't know what to do with what? The bounded part, or the ratio test part?

Comment: the bounded part

Comment: @Stu The ratio test only guarentees that for large enough $x$, the integral$$\int_x^\infty te^{-t}~\mathrm dt$$So we need to show that$$\int_0^x te^{-t}~\mathrm dt<\infty$$

Comment: Yes I understood now. I haven't thought about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The integrand function is **odd**. We just need the nature near $+\infty$.

Observe that
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}t^\color {red}{2}\cdot te^{-t}=\lim_{+\infty}t^3e^{-t}$$
$$=\lim_{+\infty}e^{-t (1-3\frac {\ln (t)}{t})}=e^{-\infty}=0$$
So for enough large $t $,

$$0 <t^\color {red }{2}\cdot te^{-t}<1 \implies  0 <te^{-t}<\frac {1}{t^\color {red}{2}} $$

the integral is then convergent by comparison test.

Comment: "because of the speed of the exponential function" is a really rigorless way of saying something. Indeed, I'd interpret "speed of the exponential function" from the limit instead of the other way around.

Comment: @ Salahamam_ Fatima $te^{-t} =\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{t^2})$ is it right?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt i changed it . thnx.

Comment: @Stu It is a little o not the big O.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima $te^{-t} =\mathcal{o}(\frac{1}{t^2}) \implies te^{-t} =\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{t^2})$

Comment: @Stu Yes but the converse is not always true.

Comment: Yup, looks good now.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima What is the english name of "le théorème des croissances comparées", if I translate in english that will give "the compared growing theorem":$(\ln x)^{\alpha}<x^{\alpha}<e^{x}$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$

Comment: Je ne pense pas que ça existe en anglais. ils disent que l'exponentielle est plus rapide.

Comment: @Salahamam_ Fatima merci, je suis originaire du maroc également...à+

Comment: @Stu Vive le Maroc.